# for error on android Studio problem occurred configuring project ':cloud_firestore

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore, resolution-independence

I am editing a taxi flutter, but it turns out that it gives me this error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':cloud_firestore'.

> defaultConfig contains custom BuildConfig fields, but the feature is disabled.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                         2,423ms
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

Does anyone know what I should do?

and trying some things, but no result as expected, it keeps giving me the same error